# TextField Covering UIAlertView's Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I am using a UIAlertView with three buttons: "Dismiss", "Submit Score" and @"View Leaderboard". The UIAlertView also contains a UITextField called username. At the moment the UITextField "username" is covering one of the buttons in the UIAlertView. I just wanted to know how I could stop the UITextField from covering one of the buttons, i.e move the buttons down.

Here is an image of what is happening:

[screenshot http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/3055/screenshot20110108at191.png](http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/3055/screenshot20110108at191.png)

And here is my code:

```
[username setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[username setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundRect];
username.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
username.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
username.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
username.placeholder = @"Enter your name here";
username = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
username.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[username resignFirstResponder];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations" 
                                                message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You tapped %i times in %i seconds!\n", tapAmount, originalCountdownTime] 
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Submit To High Score Leaderboard", @"View Leaderboard", nil];
alert.tag = 01;
[alert addSubview:username];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add some new lines and a final space at the end of the message string.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You tapped %i times in %i seconds!\n\n\n ", tapAmount, originalCountdownTime]
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason that still hasn't fixed it?

Comment: Did you also change your `CGRectMake`s? Made their `origin.y` lower?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a UIAlertView replacement class that supports user-input, custom width, and more:

https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue , your code has the following condition

```
[alert addSubview:username];
[alert show];
```

add the UITextfield after the [alert show]; as

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You tapped %i times in %i seconds!\n\n\n ", tapAmount, originalCountdownTime];
 [alert show];
 [alert addSubview:username];
```

Thats all.working fine.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use a `UIAlertView` in this manner. It was never intended for this type of user interaction and view customization:

[From the iOS Human Interface Guidelines:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW8)

> You can specify the text of the required title and optional message, the number of buttons, and the button contents in an alert. You can’t customize the width or the background appearance of the alert view itself, or the alignment of the text (it’s center-aligned).

Perhaps consider building a custom view instead?

Comment: Even if it's not specified in Apple's HIG, it's a pretty common use, and Apple uses it in some of its own apps.

Comment: Where does Apple use a `UIAlertView` with a `UITextField`? I'd be curious to see that.

Comment: when it asks for your password when downloading from the Appstore